# Asking help of pandas as groupby function?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

[image]

As my new comer for python using, could help me how to create the "Number column" by number sequence under different name of "test1" column, thanks.
(for example: pandas groupby function??)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["Number"] = (df.test1 != df.test1.shift()).cumsum()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   test1  Number
0    AAA       1
1    AAA       1
2    AAA       1
3    AAA       1
4    BBB       2
5    BBB       2
6    BBB       2
7    AAA       3
8    AAA       3
9    AAA       3
10   CCC       4
11   CCC       4
```

Comment: Many thinks for quick answer. That's so helpful to me.